# How to do simple list traversal? And how do I insert this in a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, iteration, elements

I want to make a function that takes as input a list of numbers and returns a list of 4 lists; the first returned list holds all positive real; the second returned list all negative real; the third list holds imaginary numbers; and the fourth list has others. A pretty simple question but I'm quite new to Mathematica.

Comment: something like `Through[{Select[Positive], Select[Negative], Select[x |-> x == Im[x] I && x != 0], Select[x |-> x == 0 || (Re[x] != 0 && Im[x] != 0)]}[list]]`? (this is equivalent to `{Select[list, Positive], Select[list, Negative], Select[list, x |-> x == Im[x] I && x != 0], Select[list, x |-> x == 0 || (Re[x] != 0 && Im[x] != 0)]}`)

Comment: in general, `Select[list, testf]` returns a list of elements `x` of `list` for which `testf[x]` is `True`; the criteria we're using here are the built-ins `Positive` and `Negative`, an anonymous function `x |-> ...` which checks if its argument equals its imaginary part and isn't 0, and one which checks if it's argument is equal to 0 or has a real and imaginary part both unequal to 0

Comment: (also, you can define a function with e.g. `myfunction[list_] := <the expression above>`; search the docs for "defining functions")

Comment: I get an error message saying:    Syntax: "x|" cannot be followed by "->x==Im[x]I&&x!=0".

Comment: ah, you're likely on an older version of mathematica, then; for an anonymous function, you'll either need to use `#`, `&` syntax, or explicitly `Function[x, <body>]`

Answer (score 3):

You could define a `type` function to determine the type, and then use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
type[x_] := Which[
    !TrueQ @ NumericQ[x],"Other",
    Positive[x],"Positive",
    Negative[x],"Negative",
    True, "Complex"
]
```

For example:

```
GroupBy[{1, 2, x, 3 + I, (-1)^(1/3), -BesselJZero[2,2], ZetaZero[2]}, type]
```

> <|"Positive" -> {1, 2}, "Other" -> {x},
> "Complex" -> {3 + I, (-1)^(1/3), ZetaZero[2]},
> "Negative" -> {-BesselJZero[2, 2]}|>

Answer (score 2):

```
la = {1., -2., -1., 2., I, 2 + 3 I, 4/3, 2, 0., 0, -3.};
```

Using `Query`

```
Query[Select[MatchQ @ #] & /@
   {_Real?Positive,
    _Real?Negative,
    _Complex,
    _Rational | _Integer | 0.}] @ la
```

{{1., 2.}, {-2., -1., -3.}, {I, 2 + 3 I}, {4/3, 2, 0., 0}}

If we don't want to specify the `other elements`

```
lb = {1., -2., -1., 2., I, 2 + 3 I, 4/3, 2, 0., 0, -3., ComplexInfinity, "String"};

lc =
  Query[Select[MatchQ @ #] & /@
     {_Real?Positive,
      _Real?Negative,
      _Complex,
      _}] @ lb;
```

Using `SymmetricDifference` (new in 13.1)

```
Join[Most @ lc, {SymmetricDifference @@ lc}]
```

{{1., 2.}, {-2., -1., -3.}, {I, 2 + 3*I}, {0, 0., 4/3, 2, "String", ComplexInfinity}}

Answer (score 1):

Using @eldo's data and writing for improved readability only:

```
la = {1., -2., -1., 2., I, 2 + 3 I, 4/3, 2, 0., 0, -3.};
lb = {1., -2., -1., 2., I, 2 + 3 I, 4/3, 2, 0., 0, -3., 
   ComplexInfinity, "String"};

p1 = _Real?Positive;
p2 = _Real?Negative;
p3 = _Complex;
p4 = Except[p1 | p2 | p3];

Cases[la, #] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4}
```

{{1., 2.}, {-2., -1., -3.}, {I, 2 + 3 I}, {4/3, 2, 0., 0}}

```
Cases[lb, #] & /@ {p1, p2, p3, p4}
```

{{1., 2.}, {-2., -1., -3.}, {I, 2 + 3 I}, {4/3, 2, 0., 0,
ComplexInfinity, "String"}}

---

**Using `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
f[k_List] := 
  Thread[{"PositiveReal", "NegativeReal", "Complex", 
     "Other"} -> (Scan[
        If[Head@# === Real && Positive@#, Sow[#, "PositiveReal"], 
          If[Head@# === Real && Negative@#, Sow[#, "NegativeReal"], 
           If[Head@# === Complex, Sow[#, "Complex"], 
            Sow[#, "Other"]]]] &, k] // Reap // Last)
   ];

f /@ {la, lb} // TableForm
```

---

(* same outputs *)